# Добавление элементов таблицы по клику. В чём ошибка?

Tags: html, jquery

В чём ошибка?

```
var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $("#tableCoppy").clone().appendTo("#tablePaste");
    $('#tablePaste').find('#tableCoppy').attr('id', 'div' + i);
  });
});
```

Comment: Приветствую. А в чем именно проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вероятно в том, что не надо добавлять одну таблицу внутрь другой, надо добавлять tbody внутрь table или tr внутрь tbody.
2. Id должны быть уникальны на странице, а по коду очевидно, что это не так.